# How do I render Data with Relay ,GraphQL and React

Tags: reactjs, django, graphql

I am getting this error when i try fetching data to React Frontend using GraphQL from Django Backend
Error

```
index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at EmployerInfo (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:231:75)
    at div
    at ApolloProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:6401:19)
    at App
```

This is the react code to fetch in the React frontend side

```
const QUERY_EMPLOYERS = gql`
{
    allEmployers{
      edges{
        node{
          id
          employerName
          email
          phone
          
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
export function EmployerInfo() {
  const { data, loading } = useQuery(QUERY_EMPLOYERS, {pollInterval: 500});
  
  
  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
   
  return data?.allEmployers.edges.map(({ id, employerName, email, phone }) => (
    <div key={ id }>
      <p>
        Employer - { employerName } { email }  { phone }
      </p>
    </div>
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think some of your `ids` are duplicate, try this:

```
export function EmployerInfo() {
  const { data, loading } = useQuery(QUERY_EMPLOYERS, { pollInterval: 500 });

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;

  return data?.allEmployers.edges.map(
    ({ id, employerName, email, phone }, index) => (
      <div key={`${id}-${index}`}>
        <p>
          Employer - {employerName} {email} {phone}
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: The error disappeared but does not render data on frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this code below

```
export function EmployerInfo() {
  const { data, loading } = useQuery(QUERY_EMPLOYERS, { pollInterval: 500 });

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;

  const employers = data.allEmployers.edges;

  return(
      <div>
        { employers.map( employer => {
          return <p key={employer.node.id}> Employer -  {employer.node.employerName} {employer.node.email} {employer.node.phone} </p>
        })}
      </div>
  );
}
```